# Error assigning float number within PHP array

Tags: php

My php code is as follows:

```
<?php

$rates = [
    'mmcm' => 0.1,
    'mmin' =>‪ 0.03937‬,
    'cmmm' => 10,
    'cmin' =>‪ 0.393701‬,
    'incm' => 2.54,
    'inmm' =>‪ 25.4
];
echo $rates['mmcm'];
```

For some reason this is returning the error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '0.03937' (T_DNUMBER),
>   expecting ']' in /home/PfgEBQ/prog.php on line 5

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: There are many "weird" characters in your code. I would recommend to just retype the entire code, so you don't have those characters in there.

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.19

Comment: I've just tried retyping it and it was fine. Very, very odd since I typed it manually the first time, just moments before (rather than copying and pasting it from somewhere). Thanks.

Comment: @Rizier123 can you share how you spotted the "weird" characters ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Well if you look at the code and at the error message you already know something weird is going on. Then as also described in the dupe you can use a simple hex editor and you see the characters.

Comment: @Rizier123 Ok, appreciated.